# There is no variable named "REGION"

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

The ec2 launch tempate userdata definition using the template provider is about to be replaced with a templatefile function as it is deprecated.

The definition itself can be done without any problems, but an error occurs during the planning process saying that the processing variables for getting instance metadata etc. are undefined, is there any way to avoid this?

```sh
  $ terraform version
  Terraform v0.13.5
```

```
data "template_file" "userdata" {
  template = templatefile("${path.module}/userdata.sh.tpl",
    vars....
  )
}

resource "aws_launch_template" "sample" {
....
   user_data = base64encode(data.template_file.userdata.rendered)
....
}
```

The following definitions are applicable processing

```sh
export LOCAL_IP=$(ec2metadata --local-ipv4)
export GLOBAL_IP=$(ec2metadata --public-ipv4)
export REGION=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed 's/[a-z]$//')
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="$${REGION}"
```

```
$ terraform plan
Error: failed to render : <template_file>:13,30-36: Unknown variable; There is no variable named "REGION"., and 4 other diagnostic(s)
```

thanks

Comment: What is `ec2metadata`? By default there is no such package.

Comment: Where are you running Terraform?

Comment: @Marcin, `ec2metadata` is the metadata of the launched EC2 instances.
metadata is acquired by running shell at startup
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: @JohnHanley Turn plan in  own local

Comment: I mean the program `ec2metadata`? Is it something you've installed yourself? There is no such thing on Amazon Linux 2 for instance.

Comment: You cannot access an instance's metadata from your local machine. That data is only available while executing a program/tool inside the instance. Your shell script will fail on your desktop. I do not understand what you said `Turn plan in own local`.

Comment: @JohnHanley It means that you have the terraform plan command running locally on your own desktop PC.

Comment: @jadejoe - Then the shell script attempting to access EC2 metadata will fail. Metadata is only available on AWS compute services running in the cloud and not locally.

Comment: @Marcin I'm using this one, is it wrong?

https://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-get-amazon-ec2-instance-metadata/

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm also assuming it won't succeed locally, but I'm not sure why the shell script variables are being checked in the terraform plan's execution results. To begin with, the shell should not be running locally.

Comment: @jadejoe - If the shell is not running locally, how do you execute Terraform? In other words there is a shell running that launches Terraform unless all of this is being executed by CRON or similar environment. The OP has not included all of his Terraform files, so I can only speculate. The devil is in the details and the details are missing. He is using a template file which runs a shell script. That script is failing AND the script is not detecting errors. Later Terraform plan fails with empty/missing variables.

Comment: export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="$${REGION}" should be export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="${REGION}"

Comment: It doesn't make sense to pass the result of `templatefile` into the `template_file` data source, because both that function and the data source serve the same purpose: to render a template. Because you've used them both together, you're using the result of rendering the template as a template to be rendered again. The `template_file` data source is deprecated in favor of the `templatefile` function, so you should remove the data source and use the `templatefile` function alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to use the `template_file` data source and the `templatefile` function together, because these both do the same thing: render a template.

In your current configuration, you have the `templatefile` function rendering the template to produce a string, and then the `template_file` function interpreting *that result* as if it were a template, and so your template is being evaluated twice.

The first evaluation will turn `$${REGION}` into `${REGION}` as expected, and then the second evaluation will try to handle `${REGION}` as a template interpolation.

Instead, remove the `template_file` data source altogether (it's deprecated) and *just* use the `templatefile` function:

```
   user_data = templatefile("${path.module}/userdata.sh.tpl, {
     # ...
   })
```

(I removed the `base64encode` function here because `user_data` expects an unencoded string value where the *provider itself* will do the base64 encoding. If you call `base64encode` yourself here then you'll end up with two levels of base64 encoding, which I imagine is not what you intended.)